# Is there a MemberwiseClone() equivalent in AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3

Is there a [`MemberwiseClone()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.memberwiseclone.aspx) equivalent in ActionScript3?

Comment: It's a shallow-copy; the one trivial method is just to iterate the object properties (perhaps limiting to only "has own") and shove the values into a new object. Again, note that it is a *shallow* copy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No there's no direct way to do a deep copy that's built into the language however if you're not concerned with the processing over-head and don't want to deal with writing your own clone method for each object you can use the introspection built into AS3 as described here:
http://blog.another-d-mention.ro/programming/how-to-clone-duplicate-an-object-in-actionscript-3/

Comment: can't you make deep copies of objects using `flash.utils.ByteArray`?

Comment: @TheDarkIn1978 well that's a good question.  If you could serialize any object then create a new ByteArray and just read all the bytes from the original and write bytes to a cloned ByteArray then deserialize the object into a typed class that would work.  Is this what you're thinking, have you seen this done or is there some other way you're thinking of?  Trying to look into this it would seem you would need to implement IExternalizable at the least in which case writing a clone method would be less work.

Comment: You can also create IClone interface with clone() function and implement in objects . Dont forget that simple ByteArray serialization saves only public values , so You should work with IExternalizable.

Comment: Good points, but really even a clone method would only be able to copy the publicly accessible parts (or those settable at least via the constructor arguments), after all you're only in the one instance of the class the one you have to create to return needs the properties to be write-able in order to properly clone.  I think the link I dropped is the "best" generic solution (as in not writing code for each object) if the CPU overhead is acceptable (as in not cloning thousands of objects); the clone option is "best" in terms of CPU but has pitfalls (have to code for each object).

Comment: ByteArray type solution sounded good at first because you would get the generic nature of the introspection solution but without the overhead of introspection.  But if you implement IExternalizable I feel like it's then back in the same boat as just writing a clone method on each object (idk I might be just too tired to think at this point... leaving it for now).

Comment: Just one more thing I wanted to note here, describeType is a costly call, a co-worker of mine came up with the idea of making a describeType cache object that is another Util class that keeps a dictionary of the describeType results for a given class, then looks up in that dictionary before making the actual call to describeType (probably could be made more generic to work for any function for which the return value doesn't change after the first call)